# How to select first result with mmv collisions of the 'from'?

Tags: mmv

I want to rename/move the first file of a batch of sub-directories, the problem is I don't have a rule that can target the first file based on its name (sometimes the first file of a subdir will have the same file name as a second or third file in another subdir).
And my target name is not based on the filename so it cannot be unique for each file (it is based on the directory name).

So I'd like to be able to only *match* the first result of my query like that:

```
mmv '*/*.srt'[0] '#1.srt'
```

Comment: Looking through the `mmv` man page, I'm pretty sure that's impossible.  It could be done with a complex shell script, but I think the simplest approach would likely be with zsh globs.  (I don't know zsh globs well enough to easily write a solution, but I'll look back at this when I have time later, if no one else has answered first.)